# Toggle Sliding Two Jquery Elements Results in Small Shift / Hop / Jump

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have two elements whose height depends on the view height of the page. I want to seamlessly slide up one while sliding down another. When I attempt this, content after the two elements shifts up and down a couple pixels. When I look at other examples of this double-slide, no such shifting is present. But when I recreate it, it happens. I initially suspected it was because of basing the height of the divs off of view height causes issues, but I still get the same issue with fixed height divs. I also double checked for padding and margin issues, but none are present.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ox9t3q8/ (Click on the div to slide toggle.)

HTML:

```
<div class="first swap-div">
hello world
</div>

<div class="second swap-div">
hello world
</div>

<div class="other-stuff">
hello world
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.swap-div', function() {
    $('.swap-div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

CSS:

```
.other-stuff {
  background-color: green;
}

.swap-div {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  height: 65vh;
}

.second {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the animations are not completely synchronizing every time they are run. What you can do instead is animate just one div, and have the other respond via CSS. That way, the CSS can adjust the non-animated div to fill up the necessary space without being overwritten by out-of-synch jquery.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.swap-div', function() {
  $('.first').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.other-stuff {
  background-color: green;
}

.swap-div {
  background-color: grey;
}

.swap-wrapper {
  height: 65vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.first {
  height: 65vh;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swap-wrapper">

  <div class="first swap-div">
    hello world
  </div>

  <div class="second swap-div">
    hello world1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other-stuff">
  hello world2
</div>
```

What I did was wrap the sliding divs with a wrapper that had the same height as the first div, then I set the second div to flex.